# Android recyclerview itemDecoration divider is invisible until scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've got a simple RecyclerView like this:

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/tempRv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

I add divider in `onCreate()` method in Fragment:

```
    mRv = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.tempRv);
    mRv.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
```

I also have a simple Adapter that holds the items. 
The problem is, that the divider is not visible until I scroll Up or Down the recyclerView. 
I tried:

- Scrolling programmatically by using `scrollTo(position)` method to
  the last item and the first item right after updating items in the
  adapter.
- Adding NestedScrollView as a parent and scrolling
  programmaticaly the scrollView by `fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP)`.

Nothing helps. The dividers are visible only after physical scrolling. 
The wierd thing is that I have another RecyclerViews that work fine.

**EDIT**

Due to **Sharan Salian** request to add the item layout to the post so he could reproduce this behaviour, I actually tried to reproduce it by myself. The item parent layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:transitionGroup="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:padding="16dp">
    ... 
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

I didn't mention before that I'm using the item as a **SharedElement**, that's why I added an attribute `android:transitionGroup="true"` to the parent tag. 
After removing this attribute, the **DividerItemDecoration** works fine. Once I add it, the divider is invisible until the scroll. 
Seems like just a bug.

Comment: The thing is when some tries to help you out you should accept the answer mentioning doesn't give the respected time & points for the efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Recycler View Divider Programmatically**

mRv.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(), LinearLayout.VERTICAL));

Try this above code snippet replace with **LinearLayout.Vertical** & let me know.

Can you show your item layout that you are inflating in the Adapter?

I think your item layout has an `android:orientation = "horizontal"` & you want a vertical divider. It's just an assumption as there is a very few insights I'm getting from the Question.

Comment: I use RelativeLayout as a parent for the item, so there is no android:orientation attribute. Btw, when I wrap the item layout into the CardView the divider starts working. 
Tried LinearLayout.Vertical before, unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: Can you edit your post with the layout? I'll replicate the issue and then check it out?

Comment: Your request actually helped to find the issue. I'll edit now.